# By Using Facebook Graph API, How to read Facebook wall?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am using the facebook API in my app, i know how to post message on wall. my requirement is,  i want read the wall information of user recent status information through code . 
How can i achieve this...

**for example**. from my facebook account i want to get the latest status information.

Comment: Pretty sure it's all there with the "path" interface, if you just study how it works.

Comment: @HotLicks where i will get this..

Comment: From Facebook.  (Though I now recall it's "graph", not "path" -- but it's a very complete interface, and should be able to do whatever you want.)

Comment: Hmmm, Raja says in the comments of my answer "Thank you very much i got solution from your answer."  But he opens a bounty on the question I've successfully answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a great example of using the GraphAPI to do that

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token={}`

Try it out here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

**EDIT**

I stumbled across this the other day.  There's a connection from the `user` object called `statuses`, which filters the stream even more than `feed`.  As with many graph calls, you can add `?limit=N` to limit the result set.  So this new way I discovered would look like:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?limit=1&access_token={}`

Comment: Choose a framework you want to use.  I suggest the Javascript SDK because it's the easiest one to get working quickly.  Then HTTP Get to that graph link and parse the results.

Comment: i tried to use Graph api for getting information, but no luck please check it once..

Comment: Yes, my answer still works for me.  Remember the access_token must be valid.  If can test your access token at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint.  Also see my edit above.  I've come across more information since my last response.  So now you have 2 ways to get to that information.

Comment: If you're still having issue, play around with your Graph API calls using the Graph API Explorer tool at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Sorry, but no, if you cannot read explicit directions on how to do something and you say it doesn't work, then I'm not going to waste my time chatting with you. You repeatedly refuse to go learn by playing with the explorer tool, so I cannot help people who refuse to learn.

Comment: I ready to learn i am doing with graph API from last two days still i did't get how to code, really i am not able to code even single line also . due to that reason i am asking you how to start(at least). i know how to post message/ image on facebook wall. but this is not.

Comment: Thank you very much i got solution from your answer.. but i am not able to get total messages if it is page..like if i use id/feed i am getting message posted by others, if i use id/statuses i am getting posted by owner , i want to get all messages at a time. how to do this please tell me....

Comment: You cannot get all messages it's either a bug or by design, but you're not the only one to notice this.  You should subscribe to this bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178108638946497

Answer (score 1):

You should use a third party API such as [Easy Facebook SDK](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/example.asp). It allows you to do what you are trying to do with ease.

Comment: i download from the above link, but how can i read the wall post from that.

Comment: Check out some of the availible classes http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/doc/index.html

Comment: what i want is without entering in to the face book page, i want to get the status information.

Comment: Right, easy facebook allows you to do that. Check out the demo my status.http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/example.asp

Comment: Lol @HotLicks its relatively simple

Comment: i tried to use Graph api for getting information, but no luck please check it once..

Answer (score 0):

U should check it out here:

> http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/